Why Divide by the Interest Rate in the Future Value of an Ordinary Annuity Formula?
I'm trying to understand the future value of an ordinary annuity formula, which is:
$FV = C\cdot\frac{(1 + i) ^n - 1}{i}$
Where:
$FV$ = the future value of the annuity
$C$ = the periodic payment amount
$i$ = the periodic interest rate
$n$ = the number of periods
I understand the reasoning behind most of the components of this formula, but I'm having trouble grasping why we divide by the interest rate $i$ at the end.
Can someone please explain the logic behind this step? I'd really appreciate an example walking through the full formula to help illustrate why dividing by $i$ is necessary. The reasoning behind this part of the annuity calculation has been tripping me up, so any insights would be very helpful!

@peterwhy I was wondering why I had the strangest sense of deja vu when writing my response...in all honesty when I searched my own answers I must have overlooked it.  Thanks for finding it!

After one period, the value is $C(1+i)$, after two periods is $C(1+i)+C(i+1)^2$, and so on, so after $n$ periods you have $$FV=C(1+i)+C(1+i)^2+...+C(1+i)^n$$
This is a geometric series. The sum can be written as
$$FV=C\frac{(1+i)^{n+1}-1}{(1+i)-1}$$

Your final $FV$ formula does not match the geometric series two lines above. The first term should be $C(1+i)$ with only $n$ terms.

Your first $FV$ sum would be for an annuity paid at the beginning of each period, and then valued after all $n$ periods, i.e. valued $1$ more period after the final payment.
